# U substitution of indefinite integrals like $\int \frac{5+3x}{1+x^2} dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I've spent the better part of today trying to understand conceptually how to solve indefinite integrals using the "u-substitution" method.

I am able to solve relatively easy indefinite integrals using u-substituion, but when it comes to more complicated ones I struggle and never end up with the correct answer which means i do not fully understand what is going on and am simply memorizing basic procedure for solving basic indefinite integrals.

For example:

$\int \frac{5+3x}{1+x^2} dx$

I did the following:

$\frac{5}{1+x^2} + \frac{3x}{1+x^2} dx$

$u = 1+x^2$

$du = 2x dx$

$\frac{1}{2x} du = dx$

And from there I am stuck and to be honest I don't even know if my approach is correct.

I know I am asking a lot, but is there anyone that can solve this and explain why they did what they did?

Comment: A common mistake students make: moving $x$ to the $u$ side. Don't do this!

Comment: Really? That is what a few videos online said to do. Good to know, thank you

Comment: @ Sean Roberson http://www.copingwithcalculus.com/u-substitution.html

Answer (score 3):

We have the integral $$ \int \frac{5+3x}{1+x^2} \ dx.$$ Split this according to how we add and subtract fractions, we get $$ \int \frac{5}{1+x^2} + \frac{3x}{1+x^2} \ dx.$$

The first of these integrals is just $5\arctan(x)$ (check this). For the second, we employ a substitution as follows: let $u = 1+x^2$ so $du = 2x \ dx.$ I always tell my students to "find the match," or at least something close enough to a match. We may as well write the differential as $\frac{du}{2} = x \ dx$ so that we can get a match. The integral is then rewritten as $$\int \frac{\frac{3}{2} \ du}{u}$$ which is easy to evaluate. This is just $\frac{3}{2} \ln |u| = \frac{3}{2} \ln (1+x^2)$. Combine this with the last result to get $5\arctan(x) + \frac{3}{2} \ln (1+x^2) + C.$

The moral of the story is to play to a match.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Where are you getting $\frac{3}{2} $ln$|u|$ from?

Comment: Ah ah ah, sorry, too little sleep :D. I see now. just common integral property.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int\frac{a+bx}{1+x^2}dx$$
$$I=a\int\frac{dx}{1+x^2}+b\int\frac{xdx}{1+x^2}$$
$$I=aI_1+bI_2$$

---

$$I_1=\int\frac{dx}{x^2+1}$$
$x=\tan u\Rightarrow dx=\sec^2u\ du$
$$I_1=\int\frac{\sec^2u\ du}{1+\tan^2u}$$
$$I_1=\int\frac{\sec^2u\ du}{\sec^2u}=u$$
$$I_1=\arctan x$$

---

$$I_2=\int\frac{xdx}{1+x^2}$$
$x^2=u\Rightarrow 2xdx=du\Rightarrow xdx=\frac12du$
$$I_2=\frac12\int\frac{du}{1+u}$$
$$I_2=\frac12\log|1+u|$$
$$I_2=\frac12\log|1+x^2|$$

---

$$I=a\arctan x+\frac{b}2\log|1+x^2|+C$$

Answer (score 0):

One more interesting thing of the integrations of type $$\frac {linear} {quadratic}$$ is that you can also make the linear of the form of the differentiation of the denominator.

What I mean by that in your example is that you can first separate the equations in a way like this: $$\int \frac {2x} {1+x^2} dx + \int \frac {5+x} {1+x^2}dx$$

This would directly you get the integration of the first part. For the second part, repeat the above process in a way like this:

$$\int \frac 5 {1+x^2}dx + \frac 1 2\int \frac {2x} {1+x^2}$$

This would again give you the answers directly, as you have differentiation of one above another in one part and another is just some constant multiplied to a integral formula.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{5+3x}{1+x^2}dx$$
$$=\int\frac{5}{1+x^2} + \int\frac{3x}{1+x^2}$$
$$=5\int\frac{1}{1+x^2} + \int\frac{3x}{1+x^2}$$
$$=5 \arctan x + \int\frac{3x}{1+x^2}$$
Used identity,proving will take a lot of time
$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2 + a^2}=\frac{1}{a}\arctan \frac{x}{a}$$
Moving to the second integral

$$ u = 1+x^2$$
**$$dx = 2xdu$$**
$$=\int\frac{2xkdx}{u}$$
To make both the integrals equal
$$2xk = 3x$$
where k is a constant
$$k=\frac{3x}{2x}=\frac{3}{2}$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{du}{u}$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}\ln(u)$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}\ln(1+x^2)$$
Summing up
$$\int\frac{5+3x}{1+x^2}dx=5\arctan x+\frac{3}{2}\ln(1+x^2)$$